# Light sensor issue

Tags: android, android-sensors

The code mentioned below works perfectly on samasung galaxy s(GB) but i didnt worked on SE neo v(ics) and tipo(ics). it is a sony issue or a ics issue.when started app starts and immediately display the toast "No Light Sensor! quit-".

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LightsenseActivity extends Activity {

 ProgressBar lightMeter;
 TextView textMax, textReading;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lightMeter = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.lightmeter);
        textMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.max);
        textReading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reading);

        SensorManager sensorManager 
        = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor lightSensor 
        = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        if (lightSensor == null){
        Toast.makeText(LightsenseActivity.this, 

           "No Light Sensor! quit-", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
       float max =  lightSensor.getMaximumRange();

         lightMeter.setMax((int)max);
         textMax.setText("Max Reading: " + String.valueOf(max));

         sensorManager.registerListener(lightSensorEventListener, 
           lightSensor, 
           SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        }
    }

    SensorEventListener lightSensorEventListener
    = new SensorEventListener(){

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){

    float currentReading = event.values[0];
    { lightMeter.setProgress((int)currentReading);
    textReading.setText("Current Reading: " + String.valueOf(currentReading));
   }
  }

    };
}
```

Comment: @SherifelKhatib sir that means there no light sensor on the phone. how is that possible

Comment: I do not know. But you should check the specs: Do these phones really have a light sensor

Comment: @SherifelKhatib sir, sensor music player works perfect on these phones.i think it uses light sensor.

Comment: Can you try to install AndroSensor application and see if the Light sensor shows up in it?

Comment: @VendettaDroid androsensor  shows light sensor not available

Comment: I think you should check one more thing, that is Setting->Display-> Brightness (Do you have an option to turn on/off automatic brightness? If not available then you really don't have Light Sensor on that phone. Other thing would be to check with SE about the phone specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensors listed for the SE Neo V on gsmarena (http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_neo_v-4122.php) and the Sony Xperia Tipo (http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_tipo-4718.php) are accelerometer, proximity, and compass.

A light sensor is by no means a required sensor since all it is generally used for is to adjust screen brightness. From the Android 4.0 compatibility document:

7.3.7. Photometer
    Device implementations MAY include a photometer (i.e. ambient light sensor.)

Your app is going to have to handle the case where there is no light sensor or you should add a `<uses-feature>` for `android.hardware.sensor.light` to your AndroidManifest.xml.